# DataGrid styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

vS 2008 with WPF toolkit installed and referenced.
In the Window1.xaml I added this line:

```
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
```

It runs, grid displays with data, until I attempt to style the grid. I get an error when attempting to apply a style that centers the text. The error refers to App.xaml and is:

> The type reference cannot find a public type named 'DataGridCell'. Line 9 Position 75.

My App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="DataGridStyles.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                        
StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="CenterCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: i came across the same problem , please post a solution if you found one.

Answer (score 0):

If the datagrid is part of the WPF toolkit, you'll need to add that namespace in your App.xaml too (`xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"`).

Then, just change your `TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"` to `TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}"`